# Can't remove a calendar account

Tags: calendar, horus

I've been trying to remove a calendar account but with no luck, the action itself seems to work but every time that I restart the computer, the calendar gets back again

It's a Google Calendar

[image]

**My environment**

- elementary OS 7 Horus
- Built on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- Linux 6.2.0-32-generic

Comment: Are there other calendars as well? If you are trying to remove the only calendar in the application, you may need to first create an empty one, then remove the one you no longer want. This will allow the calendar app to switch to a different default calendar 

Comment: @matigo there are no other calendars, just the default ones. I've tried creating a new empty one on the computer and assigning it as default but the Google Calendar removal still not persists when I restart the computer.